# Search a List of Objects based on List of Keywords

Tags: c#, linq, search

I have a List of this class:

```
class Stop
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and I want to search through all the stop names in the List matching all the keywords of search list and returning the matched subset.

```
List<string> searchWords = new string { "words1", "word2", "words3" ...}
```

Here is my try but I am not really sure I am on the right track

```
 var l = Stops.Select((stop, index) => new { stop, index })
            .Where(x => SearchWords.All(sw => x.stop.Name.Contains(sw)));
```

Here is an example that might make it clearer, Say I have stop with a name "Dundas at Richmond NB" and the user types in "dun", "rich" this should match and return the correct stop.

Comment: Does the code you've posted work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var l = Stops.Where(s => searchWords.Contains(s.Name)).ToList();
```

It will return `List<Stop>` will only these stops, which have coresponding string within `searchWords` collection.

To make it perform better you should consider changing `searchWords` to `HashSet<string>` first. Contains method is *O(1)* on `HashSet<T>` and *O(n)* on `List<T>`.

```
var searchWordsSet = new HashSet<string>(searchWords);
var l = Stops.Where(s => searchWordsSet.Contains(s.Name)).ToList();
```

**UPDATE**

Because of OP update, here is a version, which requires all items from `searchWords` exists in `Stop.Name` to return that particular `Stop` instance:

```
var l = Stops.Where(s => searchWords.All(w => s.Name.Contains(w)).ToList();
```

Comment: `Where` in context of LINQ will *neve* return a "list" of anything. It will return `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen You missed `ToList` call at the end of the line.

Comment: Would this ANDs the searchWords or OR them?

Comment: It will return `Stop` if there is at least one item in `searchWords` which matches `Stop.Name`. I've added version to match your question update.

Comment: The updated code works, I spent way to much time on this. Thank you so much. BTW this is the first time posting on SO and I did not expect to  be answered so quickly :) Cheers.